Why isn't the moment generator function for the beta distribution divergent?
As I understand, a  divergent integral either grows without bound or oscillates indefinitely. For example:
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx $$
When we evaluate this, we get $$ \ln|x| \big|_1^\infty = \lim_{b \to \infty} (\ln|b| - \ln|1|) = \infty $$
Recently I found that the Moment Generator Function for the Beta Distribution is divergent. I am trying to understand why this is a problem.
The Beta distribution has a probability density function (PDF) defined on the interval [0,1] (where $ B(\alpha,\beta) $ is the Beta function):
$$ f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)} $$
The MGF is defined as:
$$ M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}] = \int_0^1 e^{tx} \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)} dx $$
I think I can see the problem.
$$ \int_0^1 e^{tx} \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)} dx $$
When we're looking at behavior near $x=1$ , the term $x^{\alpha-1}$ approaches a constant since $x ≈ 1$. The Beta function $B(α,β)$ is just a constant. We are effectively dealing between $e^{tx}$ and $(1-x)^{\beta-1}$.
I can look at their ratio and limit ($h = 1-x$):
$$ \frac{e^{tx}}{(1-x)^{1-\beta}} $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{e^{tx}}{(1-x)^{1-\beta}} $$
$$ \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{e^{t(1-h)}}{h^{1-\beta}} $$
$$ = e^t \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-th}}{h^{1-\beta}} $$
For any fixed $t > 0$, as $h$ approaches $0$, the numerator $e^{-th}$ approaches 1, while the denominator $h^{1-\beta}$ approaches:

$0$ if $β < 1$
a constant if $β = 1$
$∞$ if $β > 1$

Is this the correct reason as to why the MGF for the Beta Distribution diverges? Why is this a problem? Suppose we were dealing with some other MGF (for some other random variable), how would we show that the MGF does not diverge?

Are you sure it's divergent? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moment_Generating_Function_of_Beta_Distribution

Given the title of the question is quite incorrect and could mislead future searchers, it should probably be changed.

@JoshuaP.Swanson Good point, I'll change to something better. The original title was not super informative, I tried to keep it in line with what OP was asking, but it could definitely be misleading in the future.

The MGF is never divergent for a bounded random variable.
Proof:

If $X$ is bounded then $\exp(t X)$ is bounded (for fixed $t$).

If $Y = \exp(t X)$ is bounded then $E(Y)$ is bounded too.


QED.
NB: for the beta variable, we have $\beta > 0, \alpha > 0$, otherwise we cannot normalize the integral. But the integral is finite even though the density diverges.

Beside what is given here, assuming that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive,
$$M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}] = \int_0^1 e^{tx}\, \frac{x^{\alpha-1}\,(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\, dx=\, _1F_1(\alpha ;\alpha +\beta ;t)$$ which is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.
Using its series definition
$$\, _1F_1(\alpha ;\alpha +\beta ;t)=\frac{\Gamma (\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma (a)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma (\alpha+n)}{\Gamma (n+1)\, \Gamma
   (\alpha+\beta+n)}\, t^n$$ If $a_n$ is the summand
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(\alpha+n)}{(n+1) (\alpha+\beta+n)}\,t$$ Asymptotically
$$\frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_n}=\frac{t}{n}-\frac{(\beta+1)\,t}{n^2}+
O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which confirms the convergence
